# How do I reproduce __builtin___memset_chk

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm currently working on a project in which I have to replicate the behavior of memset(). However, there is one behavior I can't seem to get. If you do something like the following:

```
char test[8] = "testing";
memset(test, 'b', 10);
```

It will give me an error at compilation(at the preprocessing stage already in fact). The error is :

```
'__builtin___memset_chk' will always overflow destination buffer
```

I am trying to replicate this behavior in my function but can't seem to figure out how it's done. I've been scouring the string.h and all related files but it's a bunch of spaghetti code that's impossible to follow. My question is this: How can I check the length of a string in the preprocessor stage to compare it to the given value?

Note: This behavior is only on Mac OS. On Linux it will happily compile and the resulting binary will simply segfault. I've tried with a few different compilers so I'm convinced this behavior is in the libraries themselves and not simply hard coded into clang.

Note 2: I would like to have my function self contained i.e. not relying on string.h

Comment: It's probably handled specially by the compiler, meaning there's really nothing you can do with your own function to replicate. Depending on the compiler, there may be special attributes you could use to inform the compiler about thing like this, and it might be able to do the same check for your function.

Comment: I've thought about this, but when I use the same clang version on Linux it doesn't give me the error. It's only on Mac.

Comment: You're probably not using the same clang version. Apple uses their own branch with extensive modifications.

Comment: memset is not writen in C but in assembler.  the C library is something outside the C language.

Comment: Ok I see. So it's not possible at all then?

Comment: @alinsoar: the fact that `memset` is assembled on a particular platform is an implementation detail, it *can* be written in C and often will be on architectures before an optimized assembly version is written.

Comment: @alinsoar: much of the C library is written in C. For example, most `malloc` implementations are written in C.

Comment: However, this particular feature is a compile-time diagnostic, and there's no obvious way to make a different compiler issue the same diagnostic. You could _almost_ do this in C++ with some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the definition of `memcpy` in the header file.

```
#define memcpy(dest, src, len)                  \
  ((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)               \
   ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest)) \
   : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
```

Unfortunately, the name "builtin" implies that this is a primitive built-in to the compiler itself, and it's not necessarily possible to replicate this behavior with your own function. Apple has an extensive set of modifications to their version of the Clang compiler. I'm curious which compilers you've tried—are you aware that the `gcc` command is an alias for clang on macOS?

There are no relevant function attributes either, which is how checks are done for e.g. `printf`.

Comment: Cool thanks. That's all I wanted to know. I am aware that gcc is an alias to clang. What I meant is that I used clang on other systems and it didn't work so I assumed that the only difference was the libraries. Didn't realize Apple had modified their clang version so much.